# Elastic thin hard material with dog nails scratch resistant

Tags: materials, bending

Im looking for a an elastic thin material for hinge and running surface for a dog to glue on wood (I would just use wood but i'm afraid it will splinter)

It should be able to bend 45 deg with ease, can bond to wood and is not slipery

Any idea of what I can use?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the term "elastic" to means something flexible and not necessarily stretchy, consider that leather is a good choice. Leather can be bonded to wood using mechanical means (bolts, furring strips, etc) as well as with various adhesives. Using mechanical fasteners allows for easy replacement as required.

I've constructed leather hinges which have lasted for years, although under occasional use rather than constant use. Periodic treatment with an oil or leather conditioner also improves lifespan.

I'd like to see video of the dog gluing the material of choice to the wood.